С помощью каких фреймворков делаются интеграционные тесты?
Интеграционные тесты делаются с помощью тех же MSTest и подобных фреймворков ?
Т.е. как и юнит тесты просто с учётом реальных и тестовых зависимостей ?
Или какие то отдельные фреймоврки специально под интеграционные тесты ?

Интересный вопрос. А что именно вы хотите протестировать?

В общем, да, именно как вы написали. Пример: Integration tests in ASP.NET Core

@CrazyElf я пока просто тренируюсь с тестированием в консольном приложении с несколькими компонентами, которые работают в фоне, берут данные с БД, проводят над ними работу, размещают в БД для других компонентов и т.д.
